# Advice on using GitHub

Tags: git, netbeans, github

I've recently started using GitHub. I am working on a project both on my work PC and my home PC. The problem I've encountered is that when I make changes on my work PC and 'push' the changes to GitHub, when I go home and want to 'pull' these changes onto my home PC, it doesn't seem to work - it comes up with some error (I can't remember exactly what it said, but something to do with breaking a rule about checking out files). Basically this is what I want to happen:

1. Make changes on my work PC and update the GitHub repository with
   those changes
2. Go home and replace whatever I had on my home PC with the updated
   project from GitHub
3. Make changes on my home PC and update the GitHub repository with
   those changes
4. Go to work and replace whatever I had on my work PC with the updated
   project from GitHub

How do I achieve this? I am using Netbeans so am doing all Git related stuff through that.

### Update

The commands I am using at the moment are:
After finishing a batch of changes I click Git > Commit and then Git > Remote > Push to save it to GitHub.

When I get to my home PC and want to replace my current project with the one on GitHub I click Git > Remote > Pull.

Comment: Without knowing the commands you use and the error message you get, it's hard to answer.

Comment: Please see update for the commands I am using at the moment - still can't remember the error though, I will post it when I encounter it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea works fine, it sounds like you are just inexperienced with git.  There are many tutorials available online, it takes a little getting used to.

The issue you *may* be encountering is a `git pull` will bark at you if you have uncommitted changes locally when trying to pull.  Make sure you have a clean, committed state when you pull and it'll work.

Also, if you have committed but un-pushed changes, a pull will try to merge those changes, since that's what you asked it to do.  Often this won't really be a problem, but conflicts can happen, and you'll need to resolve them when it does.  This is just a normal occurrence with version control and something you should get used to dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are having issues with conflicting line endings due to switching between Mac and PC... There should be a way to set your application of choice to use consistent line endings.